# Show only 10 records in FaltList React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm getting data from API into `FlatList` in my expo app but the issue is there is more than 500+ records but I want to show only 10 records in `FlatList` so is there any way to do that?

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            itemList: []
        }
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('myApiUri')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    itemList: response.data
                });
                console.log("Data", response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log("Errorrr:" + error))
    }
    // renderItem(data) {
    //     return (

    //     );
    // }
    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.itemList}

                    // columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-around", flex: 1 }}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                    horizontal
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={{ width: 150, paddingHorizontal: 3 }}>
                                <Card style={{ height: 200, padding:0 }}>
                                    <CardItem>
                                        <Body>
                                            <Image source={{ uri: item.MainImg }} style={{ width: '100%', height: 150 }} />
                                            {item.ItemName.length > 10 ? <Text style={style.productTitle} numberOfLines={1}>{item.ItemName.substring(0,18) + '...'}</Text> : <Text numberOfLines={1} style={style.productTitleLess}>{item.ItemName}</Text>}
                                        </Body>
                                    </CardItem>
                                </Card>
                            </View>
                        );
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.ID}
                />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add capability of paginating in your back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By slicing the array:

```
  <FlatList
                    data={this.state.itemList.slice(0, 10)}
```

Comment: love it ! works on me ! bless you dude

Answer (score 0):

When you have a lot of data to show in a list, especially when it's around 500+, it is always good to maintain it as a paginated response from the backend; and then pass only up to 10 values to the `FlatList` component.

What you can do here, in your case is, paginate it from the frontend.

Your constructor will be like,

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        itemList: [],
        pages: 0,
        currentPage: 0
    }
}
```

And your componentWillMount axios call will have a callback like,

```
(response) => {
     const pages = response.data / 10;
     this.setState({
          itemList: response.data,
          pages
     }
);
```

Now that you have data in the state, let's render it into FlatList component. In `render()`,

```
const { itemList, currentPage } = this.state;
const startingIndex = currentPage + 10;
const endingIndex = startingIndex + 10;
const data = itemList.slice(startingIndex, endingIndex);
```

And pass the data to `FlatList` like `data={data}`.

You'll need to have a paginated button component, and for which you will have a onChange functionality which can be maintained like,

```
handlePageChange = (currentPage) => {
    this.setState({
        currentPage
    })
}
```

P.S. here, the index based on the page is maintained assuming the page number will be maintained on 0 indexing.